# Is it possible get data for grafana dashboards user specifically?

Tags: sql-server, angular, grafana

I'm currently working on integrating `grafana` into a angular web application for dash boarding purposes. Where I'm stuck in the scenario of how to let user specific datasets for users dashboards.

For example : -  In SQL server If there is user called `A`. `A`should only get all the data which is related to himself. This is simply can be archived via `SQL- WHERE` clause. But i want to know weather if it possible to do it on the fly without using query editor on `grafana` dashboard. Query editor should get data only relevent to the specific user. In this scenario Query editor should get data which belongs to user `A`.

-Is it possible in grafana?
-Also i would like to know how much effort will it take to alter the css of the 
grafana dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello everyone after some research we found out that.. It is possible to facilitate grafana with the data fetched from REST END point call. So it can be archived via the REST call using built plugin in  grafana. Next question is mainly how much of effort that has to be done to white label grafana in web solution. grafana will have lot of effort when it comes to white labeling grafana via css.